# Prevent ListView scrolling automatically when typing in a TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, mobile-development, textformfield

In my case, I have a bottom-placed TextFormField above ListView, user can type multiline in TextFormField, but when the user is typing in TextFormField the ListView starts to scroll up automatically, The top tab bar is implemented in a NestedScrollView, and TextFormField is placed in a Stack view, Is there any way to stop that weird behavior.

[image]

here is the code that include listview

```js
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Log.debug("rebuild comment view");
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: false,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: timeline != null
                  ? UserDetailsCard(
                      timeline: timeline,
                    )
                  : SizedBox(),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
                  child: timeline != null
                      ? ExpandableText(
                          timeline.post.content,
                          TimelineTextStyles.regular14BlackStyle(),
                          AppColors.lightGreen,
                          isEventWidgetEnable: false,
                          isThumbnailEnable: false,
                        )
                      : SizedBox()),
            ),
            SliverSafeArea(
              top: false,
              bottom: false,
              sliver: SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true,
                floating: false,
                snap: false,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                toolbarHeight: 0,
                collapsedHeight: 0,
                expandedHeight: 0,
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kTextTabBarHeight),
                  child: timeline != null ? Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 4,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 20),
                          child: TabBar(
                            isScrollable: true,
                            indicatorColor: AppColors.lightGreen,
                            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                            labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
                            indicatorWeight: 3,
                            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.darkGrey,
                            labelColor: Colors.white,
                            indicator: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              color: AppColors.lightOrange,
                            ),
                            tabs: [
                              for (var tab in _tabsName)
                                Text(
                                  "$tab",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ],
                            onTap: (index) {},
                            controller: _tabController,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ) : SizedBox(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: _tabController != null
            ? TabBarView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: _tabs,
                controller: _tabController,
              )
            : Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: As per the video, i can see that the text field is getting bigger with addition of lines, maybe can you try to add overflow for the text field and so the size is constant ? Or you want the implementation to remain ?

Comment: As you said I want to remain that textfield behavior, Is there a way to fix the issue by keeping the textfield implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you retain one property while implementing the opposite property?  Can you have a top on the bottom?

No.

Comment: thanks for the comment but I didn't get what you said..